# socket error when try to start mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm try to use mysql on ubuntu 16.04. When I execute `mysql -u root -p`, I get this error: `'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'`

In the error.log file, I see this error alert:

```
2020-10-24T15:43:52.556275Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to create a socket for IPv4 '127.0.0.1': 
errno: 13.
2020-10-24T15:43:52.556289Z 0 [ERROR] Can't create IP socket: Permission denied
2020-10-24T15:43:52.556299Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I try to uninstall and reinstall mysql, but without any result. How can I solve this problem ?

---

Edit:
With `sudo systemctl status mysql.service`, I get this:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor 
 preset: disabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-10-25 15:05:42 CET; 
 4min 5s ago
Process: 18804 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre 
(code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

 Oct 25 15:05:42 thales systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart 
 job, restart counter is at 5.
 Oct 25 15:05:42 thales systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
 Oct 25 15:05:42 thales systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request 
 repeated too quickly.
 Oct 25 15:05:42 thales systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 
 'exit-code'.
 Oct 25 15:05:42 thales systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community 
 Server.
```

---

This is the entire log inside `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

```
2020-10-25T12:46:01.869691Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] 
/usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21) initializing of server in progress as 
process 16663
2020-10-25T12:46:01.869808Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010338] [Server] Can't find 
error-message file '/usr/share/mysql-8.0/errmsg.sys'. Check error- 
message file location and 'lc-messages-dir' configuration directive.
2020-10-25T12:46:01.880669Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB 
initialization has started.
2020-10-25T12:46:04.317333Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB 
initialization has ended.
2020-10-25T12:46:09.821004Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] 
root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider 
switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2020-10-25T12:46:22.034576Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] 
/usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21) starting as process 16714
2020-10-25T12:46:22.034766Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010338] [Server] Can't find 
error-message file '/usr/share/mysql-8.0/errmsg.sys'. Check error- 
message file location and 'lc-messages-dir' configuration directive.
2020-10-25T12:46:22.061157Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB 
initialization has started.
2020-10-25T12:46:23.091350Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB 
initialization has ended.
2020-10-25T12:46:23.368045Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011292] [Server] Plugin 
mysqlx reported: 'Preparation of I/O interfaces failed, X Protocol 
won't be accessible'
2020-10-25T12:46:23.368243Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011300] [Server] Plugin 
mysqlx reported: 'Setup of bind-address: '*' port: 33060 failed, 
`socket()` failed with error: Permission denied(13)'
2020-10-25T12:46:23.368395Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013597] [Server] Plugin 
mysqlx reported: 'Value '*' set to `Mysqlx_bind_address`, X Plugin 
can't bind to it. Skipping this value.'
2020-10-25T12:46:23.368552Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011300] [Server] Plugin 
mysqlx reported: 'Setup of socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' 
failed, can't create lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock.lock'
2020-10-25T12:46:23.727103Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA 
certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-10-25T12:46:23.727337Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel 
mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now 
supported for this channel.
2020-10-25T12:46:23.728781Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010250] [Server] Failed to 
create a socket for IPv4 '0.0.0.0': errno: 13.
2020-10-25T12:46:23.729006Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010255] [Server] Can't 
create IP socket: Permission denied
2020-10-25T12:46:23.729451Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-10-25T12:46:25.486906Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] 
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21)  MySQL Community 
Server - GPL.
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, how about `sudo systemctl start mysql`

Comment: Thanks @user.dz. I recieve `Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` and if I execute the first command I see `Failed to start MySQL Community Server.`

Comment: Would you edit the question and add output of `sudo systemctl status mysql.service`

Comment: I add it in the post. Thanks

Comment: Maybe [AppArmor denied the creation of the socket](https://serverfault.com/questions/847891/mysql-start-error-failed-to-create-a-socket-for-ipv4-127-0-0-1-errno-13). Look for an error message similar to the one in the linked answer.

Comment: No clear error message in that output. Could you share content of logs in `/var/log/mysql/` and try again with `sudo mysql -u root -p`  add output to the question.

Comment: add log file in my post

Comment: Try first `sudo service mysql start` and `sudo mysql -u root -p`

Comment: @BishwasBhandari with `sudo service mysql start ` i get `Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
`

Comment: Please give the permissions to MySQL with `chown mysql.mysql /var/run/mysqld/`

Comment: @BishwasBhandari done, but nothing is changed

Comment: Can you show me the change error. You can uninstall MySQL and reinstall it. Perhaps it'll help.

Comment: The errors are always the same `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`. I have already uninstall and reinstall sql, but nothing